# How to set state for text box in functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React JS. I have one text-box component and I want to show some default value in it. After that, the user should be allowed to change the value. Now I am unable to change the value. The text box is behaving like read-only. Below is my code

```
const EditStyleFormComponent = ({
submitting,
invalid,
}) => (
  <form className={className} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <h2>LSPL (Low Stock Presentation Level)</h2>
    <Line />
    <InputGroup>
       <TextFieldWithValidation name="lsplMan" label="LSPL Manual" input={{ onChnage:'', value: 'Current' }} />
    </InputGroup>
 </form>
);
```

Below is my TextFieldWithValidation code.

```
export const TextFieldWithValidationComponent = ({
  meta,
  input,
  noStyles,
  ...otherProps
}) => (
  <TextField
    state={noStyles ? textFieldStates.DEFAULT : getState(meta)}
    errorMessage={meta.touched ? meta.error : null}
    {...input}
    {...otherProps}
  />
);
```

Below is my TextField code.

```
const TextField = ({
  className,
  label,
  description,
  state,
  errorMessage,
  isEditable,
  spaceAtBottom, // Not used, but we don't want it in otherProps
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const inputId = _.uniqueId();

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {label &&
        <label htmlFor={inputId}>{label}</label>
      }
      <div className="input-group" id={isEditable ? 'editable' : 'readonly'}>
        <input
          id={inputId}
          readOnly={!isEditable}
          {...otherProps}
        />
        {getStatusIcon(state)}
        {errorMessage &&
          <Error>{errorMessage}</Error>
        }
        {description &&
          <Description>{description}</Description>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can u share your code pen or sandbox ,so that it will be easier to debug

Comment: `onChnage` is `string`? it should set the state of the input's value.

Comment: Use React hooks to use state in functional components. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yu defined `onChange` as empty string in `EditStyleFormComponent` component. So on any change input component just do nothing.

`onChange` should be some function that will update value.

If you want to use functional components there are two possible solutions:

1. [Lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to parent component of `EditStyleFormComponent` (in case parent is class based component)
2. Use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) like so (just example!)

   ```
   const EditStyleFormComponent = ({
       submitting,
       invalid,
   }) => {
       const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState ('Current'); // default value goes here
       return <form className={className} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
           <h2>LSPL (Low Stock Presentation Level)</h2>
           <Line />
           <InputGroup>
               <TextFieldWithValidation name="lsplMan" label="LSPL Manual" input={{ onChnage: (e) => { setInputValue(e.target.value); }, value: inputValue }} />
           </InputGroup>
       </form>
   };
   ```

Comment: hi Thanks for sharing code. I added above code and I started getting error Parsing error: The keyword 'let' is reserved. May I know where should I declare [inputValue, setInputValue] ?

Comment: Sorry, there should be `const`. I've modified the code

Answer (score 8):

You can use State Hook for manage state in functional component. 
Example :

```
const Message = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState( '' );

  return (
    <div>
      <input
         type="text"
         value={message}
         placeholder="Enter a message"
         onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
       />
      <p>
        <strong>{message}</strong>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```